# Determine the highest grade achieved for the midterm for each section

Tags: sql, counter

I am a beginner and I am having a bit of trouble with the following query:

I am trying to determine the highest grade achieved for the midterm for each section.

This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT TOP 1 GRADE.NUMERIC_GRADE, GRADE.SECTION_ID, GRADE.GRADE_TYPE_CODE 
FROM GRADE
WHERE GRADE_TYPE_CODE = 'MT' AND
COUNT SECTION_ID = 1
ORDER BY NUMERIC_GRADE, GRADE_TYPE_CODE, SECTION_ID
```

I keep getting this:ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Am I doing to much (should I create a view first)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the table if it helps:

```
GRADE
GRADE_CODE_OCCURRENCE (PK) NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL
STUDENT_ID (PK)(FK) NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL
SECTION_ID (PK)(FK) NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL
GRADE_TYPE_CODE (PK)(FK) CHAR(2) NOT NULL
NUMERIC_GRADE NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL
COMMENTS VARCHAR2(2000) NULL
CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
CREATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL
MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
MODIFIED_DATE DATE NOT NULL
```

Comment: I don't think Oracle supports `TOP`.  Try `WHERE ROWNUM = 1`

Comment: @Mike Christensen I put this: SELECT GRADE.NUMERIC_GRADE 
FROM GRADE
WHERE ROWNUM = 1, 
SELECT GRADE.SECTION_ID, GRADE.GRADE_TYPE_CODE 
FROM GRADE
WHERE GRADE_TYPE_CODE = 'MT' AND
COUNT SECTION_ID = 1
ORDER BY NUMERIC_GRADE, GRADE_TYPE_CODE, SECTION_ID Now I get this message:WHERE ROWNUM = 1,
                *
ERROR at line 3: 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended I am guessing the structure is not correct...any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using a GROUP BY:

```
select GRADE.SECTION_ID,  max(GRADE.NUMERIC_GRADE)
from GRADE
group by GRADE.SECTION_ID
```

Comment: thank you sir that group by worked. Is my previous attempt possible or is this just a case of a better structure being used? Again thank you both, I am still attempting to learn the ropes.

Comment: The stated problem is exactly matched by the use of a GROUP BY; your previous attempt addresses different problems. With experience you will learn to recognize these.